# How to request user info with openid connect

Tags: php, keycloak, openid-connect, http-status-code-400

I am trying to request userinfo via our OpenID Connect Keycloak server. When requesting the acces_token, everything will go fine. But as soon as I request userinfo, I get error 400.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;

    $username = $_REQUEST["Username"];
    $password = $_REQUEST["Password"];

$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient(
    'xxx',
    'yyy',
    'zzz'
);
$oidc->providerConfigParam(array('userinfo_endpoint'=>'xxx/userinfo_endpoint'));

$oidc->addScope('openid');
$oidc->addScope('roles');
$oidc->addScope('profile');

//Add username and password
$oidc->addAuthParam(array('username'=>$username));
$oidc->addAuthParam(array('password'=>$password));

//Perform the auth and return the token (to validate check if the access_token property is there and a valid JWT) :
session_start();
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $oidc->requestResourceOwnerToken(TRUE)->access_token;
// $token = $oidc->requestResourceOwnerToken(TRUE)->access_token;

try {
    $name = $oidc->requestUserInfo();
} catch (\Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClientException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

This gives the following errorcode:

```
 The communication to retrieve user data has failed with status code 400
```

I know this has something to do with the formatting or something alike, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Can someone please point me in the general direction?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Okay, so I will answer my own question in case anyone comes across the same errors as I do.

Normally all endpoints are automatically found via `https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/<realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration` if you enter the issuer, or at least, I thought so.

It turned out that i missed the `jwks_uri` endpoint.

So I entered the endpoint, and voila. I was able to request all information.

```
<?php
include 'session.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;

    $oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient(
        'https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/Infra',
        'xxx',
        'yyy'
    );
    $oidc->setRedirectURL('https://<redirect-url>');
    $oidc->providerConfigParam(array('authorization_endpoint'=>'https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/Infra/protocol/openid-connect/auth'));
    $oidc->providerConfigParam(array('userinfo_endpoint'=>'https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/Infra/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'));
    $oidc->providerConfigParam(array('token_endpoint'=>'https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/Infra/protocol/openid-connect/token'));
    $oidc->providerConfigParam(array('jwks_uri'=>'https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/Infra/protocol/openid-connect/certs'));
    $oidc->addScope('email');
    $oidc->addScope('profile');
    $oidc->addScope('openid');
    $oidc->getAuthParams();    
    
    
    $_SESSION['oidc'] = $oidc;
    $oidc->authenticate();
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your userinfo endpoint `xxx/userinfo_endpoint` is not correct endpoint:

```
array('userinfo_endpoint'=>'xxx/userinfo_endpoint')
```

Visit your Keycloak discovery url, e.g. `https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/<realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration` and get correct userinfo endpoint from there.

Comment: Well, I got my endpoint from that configuration. I copied it directly from there, even tried it without setting that param. Because, as I understand it, it should be able to configure its own correct endpoints from the issuer.